# Python concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() adding values ​twice. How to fix it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, concurrent.futures

I am trying to create a bot to access a website and automatically update certain relevant information for each user (for reasons beyond my control I cannot do it directly from the database). For this I am using Selenium. So far I can access the site and update the data of a user successfully, however, as there are many users I would like to be able to create multiple instances (at least 2) of webdriver to make the process faster. For this I am trying with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() to create multiple processes and pass the information of a user to each of them.

At this point I have not been successful because when the instances are created and the login site is visited, the data is only sent in one of the instances. For example, the code I have is as follows:

```
user_login = "username"
user_pass  = "password"
data = {}
data["key1"] = "some value"
data["key2"] = "some value"

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(functions.create_webdriver_instances, user_login, user_pass, key1, key2) for key1, key2 in data.items()]

            for future in futures:
                future.result()
```

When the script is executed, what happens is that the 2 webdriver instances are created but only the first one loads the data. That is, on the login screen of the web page, the username is entered twice and the password is entered twice. In the second instance, no value is entered. Any idea where I'm failing?

I have also tried defining two users, each with the corresponding data, and then executing the executor.submit() twice, but the result is the same.